# Most convenient way to perform an HTTP request in a series of commands (Swift)

Tags: swift, httprequest

I have a view with some text fields. When the user clicks "Finish" I verify that each field is not empty. Two of those fields are an email address and a username field. I want to verify that the email address and username aren't already in use in my database.

I've built an HTTP request that performs the checks, but the rest of the code executes before I get a response back.

```
if username.text == "" {
    // Alert user
    return
}

if email.text == "" {
    // Alert user
    return
}

let server = ServerController() // Custom HTTP request object I made

server.DoesUsernameExist(username: username.text!)
server.DoesEmailExist(email: email.text!)

// Properties server.usernameExists and server.emailExists begin as nil and are set to true or false with server.DoesUsernameExist() and server.DoesEmailExist()

if server.usernameExists == true {
    // Alert user
    return
}

if server.emailExists== true {
    // Alert user
    return
}

server.CreateProfile(/* parameters */) // Creates a new entry in the database
```

But the properties server.usernameExists and server.emailExists are still nil when server.CreateProfile() is executed.

I would love something as simple as this:

```
let emailExists = server.DoesEmailExist(email: email.text!)

if emailExists == true {
    // Alert user
    return
}
```

But not having any luck with that. I'm new to doing HTTP requests in Swift.

Any advice would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use threaded checks? Maybe closure blocks? This isn't necessarily related to a language issue (Swift). For instance, the code you've shown - is it the code you are trying? Everything is not only on the main thread, it's not looking for completion/closure, which *certainly* isn't restricted (in terms of HTTP requests) to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the code that would be THAT simple is technically impossible. You can't simply write that because call to a server is async operation (it happens over time, not instantly like a = 2+2 operation for example). Therefore your best bet is to use callbacks that would trigger after server responds to a request. It would be something within the lines:

1. after user types in the name, you start API call to server and add
   flag that marks that it's in progress.
2. If response to this call is received before user submits registration -> you update the UI accordingly by showing the message that it's not unique
3. If response is not received by the time user presses submit, you disable ALL UI elements, display activity indicator and wait for the response of that call
4. (3a) If response when received says it's unique username
   you proceed to with registration, otherwise you reenable UI and
   provide user with the feedback that username exists.

Alternatively, you could split this into couple of steps, where after user enters the name, he has to press the button, after which you disable the UI and wait for the server response. If that is successful you proceed to step #2, etc. Hope this helps.